# Unable to disable back button once a form is submitted to firebase

Tags: forms, dart, flutter, back

once i fill the form and submit it to Firebase,the code navigates me to my homepage but as soon as i press back button of my android phone, it send's user to previous form page with all previous filled data is available. i have tired using **WillPopScope** function to disable back button of my android phone but no response..

i have also created a function using **willpopscope** and called it in main but no result.

```
            @override
              Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                  return new WillPopScope(
                      onWillPop: () async =>false,
                   child: new Scaffold(
                   appBar: new AppBar(
                  title: new Text('Welcome'),
                    actions: <Widget>[
                       _onbackpressed(), //tried disabling the back button by calling this fucntion
                       new FlatButton(
                      child: new Text('Logout',
                          style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0, color: Colors.white)),
                      onPressed: _signOut)
                   ],
                  ),
              body: _showTodoList(),
                floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                                    onPressed: () {
                               signupPage(context);

                          },
                           tooltip: 'Increment',
                           child: Icon(Icons.add),
                 )

              ),
            );
          }

     //extra funtion to disable the back button-
   _onbackpressed(){
    return new WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async =>false, 
       child: new Container(width: 0.0,height: 0.0,),  
       );


     }


         //function used to send the user form to server

                  RaisedButton(
                       elevation: 7.0,
                        child: Text('Upload'),
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        onPressed: () {
                              final StorageReference firebaseStorageRef =
                              FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(Username);
                              final StorageUploadTask task =
                              firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_image);
                              success(context);

                             },
                   ),

        //where success is a fuction 
              success(BuildContext context){
      Navigator.of(context)
     .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context)=>Redirect() ));
 }
```

Comment: Could you show the function you use to send the user back from the form to the main page?

Comment: success(BuildContext context){
    Navigator.of(context)
    .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context)=>Redirect() ));
  }

Comment: So did it work?

Comment: It did,you're awesome. thank you happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of pushing a new screen when the user submits the form, you should pop it, like this:

```
success(BuildContext context){
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
}
```

The reason for this is because you have a stack of screens. When the user is done with one, you should send him back to where you want, instead of putting another one on the top and leaving the already used one on the stack.

Comment: @YASHWANT glad to help :) Please accept the anser by clicking the tick under the voting button.